# woocommerce_package_rates not fired when wordpress woocommerce accessed as non ajax

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, hooks

I use woocommerce_package_rates hook on woocommerce so I could change the flat rate on checkout page, but the problem is when someone access the checkout page without js enabled, it will cause the woocommerce_package_rates no fired, I tried multiple ways to test but It doesn't fired at all. If it's a js enable browser, it works. Any Suggestion ?